# How to plot fraction values in a graph x-axis using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following array:

```
np.array([0,1/3.,2/3.,1])
```

I want to write this values in the fraction form in a graph x-axis using matplotlib, anyone knows how to do it?

for example:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

X = np.array([0,1/3.,2/3.,1])
Y = 2*X
plt.xticks(np.unique(X))
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you just write the fractions to the x-axis tick labels as strings "0", "1/3", "2/3", "1" (this would be easy); or do you need a generalized approach to a fractional representation of the number so, for example, you could just as easily do 3/7, or whatever (this would be harder)?

Comment: Yes, I need a generalized approach.

Comment: Then you need to specify the problem a bit more... Will equally spaced fractional points always be given; will the max always be 1 and then you want the axis divided up; etc?

Comment: The array could be any, what I want to know is if I have some fraction number inside this array, how to write this number in a fraction form. If there's a format function to do this, for example.

Comment: you might want to look into this https://docs.python.org/2/library/fractions.html

Comment: Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it is the best solution, but it works for me:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from fractions import Fraction

X = np.array([0,1/3.,2/3.,1])
Y = 2*X
X_tick = np.array([])
for item in X:
    X_tick = np.append(X_tick,Fraction(item).limit_denominator())
plt.xticks(np.unique(X),X_tick)
plt.plot(X,Y)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner version of the answer by @dalmeida13 using a list comprehension:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from fractions import Fraction
import numpy as np

X = np.array([0,1/3.,2/3.,1])
Y = 2*X

X_tick = [Fraction(item).limit_denominator() for item in X]
plt.xticks(np.unique(X), X_tick)
plt.plot(X,Y)
plt.show()
```

which results in the same outcome.